# Ionic pro build failed with error No provisioning profiles provided with Xcode 9

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, xcode9, provisioning-profile

I have a problem when build Ionic 2 application with XCode9. It returns an error: "No provisioning profiles provided".

I'm using Ionic Pro service to build native package. When I select XCode8, the build run successfully.

My application is an old application, now I'm update a new version for it. This application has a App Prefix ID different from Team ID (this app created long time ago). I'm not sure this is the root cause of the problem.

I've tried to build my app with different App ID (new one), it works fine on Xcode9.

AppID: 96DGSVAS31.com.nguyentr.myApp

TeamID: ABCDERGGG

So could anyone please help me to solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by building my Ionic app for iOS using **Xcode9 on my Macbook**. The problem is the Ionic Pro service's build process is using different code signing approach.

Cheers.